# Importing an Excel document with openxlsx cuts off columns

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to export some tables from R to Excel using the `openxlsx` package and I'm using the following command to autofit the column widths:

```
setColWidths(Workbook,Worksheet, cols = 1:9, widths = "auto")
```

The widths are changing but they're slightly too short and some text is being cut off. I've checked in the Excel file and it seems to be rounding to the nearest integer.

Is there any way to fix the "auto" column widths in `openxlsx`? I've tried checking the source code but I don't understand it well enough. Or are there any alternatives other than having to manually set widths for each column?

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what your question is (= there isn’t any).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function:

```
  colExcelAutofit <- function(df, size, n = 50, span = 2) {
defaultsize <- 12
# multiplier depende de tipo de fuente {1.61803 número de oro, 2, o un número del 1 al 2}
multiplier <- 1.61803 # número de oro. 

width_vec <- apply (
  head (df, n), 2, 
  function(x) max (nchar (as.character (x)) + span, na.rm = TRUE)
)
width_vec_header <- nchar (colnames (df)) + span
max_vec_header <- pmax (width_vec, width_vec_header)
return (max_vec_header * multiplier ^ ((size - defaultsize) / 2))}
```

font:

> https://blog.envylabs.com/responsive-typographic-scales-in-css-b9f60431d1c4

but I have problems with the extra characters the column style adds (ex: currency + space chars). Function need more detail